# What are the difference between DatastoreService and DatastoreServiceFactory

Tags: java, google-app-engine

```
DatastoreService dts = new DatastoreServiceFactory();
```

but it is showing an error and it says. I need to change dts as `DatastoreServiceFactory` 
Can someone, help me figure out why this error is occurring?

Comment: A look at the google-app-engine documentation (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreServiceFactory) for this class shows the constructor is deprecated and not to be instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

The DatastoreService provides synchronous access to a schema-less data storage system. This one, can be used transactionally and supports the notion of a "current" transaction. A current transaction is established by calling beginTransaction().

```
 DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory
            .getDatastoreService();
```

The application obtains DatastoreService instances from a DatastoreServiceFactory.

```
  Transaction txn=datastore.beginTransaction();
```

...implementation....

```
 txn.commit();
```

Comment: Look this example: http://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory